# How to switch layers using checkbox in Openlayers 3

Tags: javascript, html, openlayers-3

I'm trying to switch layers using a checkbox, but the switch from "baselayer" to "topo" doesn't work. Please help:

```
<body>
    <div id="mapa"></div>
    <nav id="layers">
        <ul>
            <li><input type="radio" name="layer" value="baseLayer" checked>ORTO</li>
            <li><input type="radio" name="layer" value="topo"> TOPO</li>
            <li><input type="radio" name="layer" value="untiled"> Warstwa</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
```

A [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b2L6qppd/40/) is also available.

Comment: What is this `source: new ol.source.ToPo` . This type of source doesnt exist on ol3. How did you come up with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fiddle will not work for varius reasons.

1. You do not include jquery but you use it within your code
2. `source: new ol.source.ToPo` doesnt exist. It is unknow for openlayers. Maybe it is just a typo. But I have changed it to `ol.source.TileWMS`.

Here is your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/b2L6qppd/41/) reconstructed. It takes some time to load the images, but this has to do with your server.

Also consider to upgrade to the latest ol3 version. 3.7.0 is too old!

Comment: How to make the layer "untiled" always on top?

Comment: Do you mean to be always switched on ? OR you just want to be on top of other layers?

Comment: Just want to be on top of other layers.